# jsuml is working with my eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml

I downloaded jsuml-eclipse-0.8.4 from http://jsuml.gaertner-network.de/.
I put all the plugin jars in eclipse plugin folder and start eclipse in clean mode. Still i am unable to see the plugin in plugin installed in eclipse --> preferences --> plugin.
I am using eclipse helios on mac with snowlapord OS.

If any one know some good code to UML diagram in javascript please suggest.

Regards
Mahaveer

Comment: Can anybody please suggest me how to install jsUML plugin?

Answer (score 0):

At least you should ensure you use Eclipse 3.7.1 (Indigo). Newer versions wont work so far since some incompatibilites have brought in but the plugin was never adapted to that.
I managed it to get jsuml working, although I'm still not able to parse my .js files in.